# How do I compare the value of password stored in CoreData with user input?

Tags: swift, core-data, ios8, xcode6

This is the code for login page where I want to compare input with stored data.
    import UIKit

```
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userName: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordText: UITextField!

@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {

var appdel : AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)

var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appdel.managedObjectContext!

var request1 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")

NSEntityDescription newUser = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username == %@ AND password == %@",self.UsernameTextField.Text, self.PasswordTextField.Text];

var result : NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request1, error: nil)!

if (result.count > 0 ){

 println("true")

}

context.save(nil)

}
```

Comment: Did you mix Objective-C with Swift code in the same file ??

Comment: Are you really storing passwords in plain text? I hope they're not for anything even slightly important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your almost correct, and only one more step needed to make magic happen. Thats to set predicate to request like following

```
request1.predicate = predicate
```

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate is correct. But you should set into your request.

Four considerations:

- you don't need to `save` the context
- you should not store credentials in Core Data. Maybe the Keychain will be suitable for this.
- variable should be named with `camelNotation`. e.g `usernameTextField` and not `UsernameTextField`
- why Objective-C and Swift code in the same file?

Comment: request1 has no predicate and that will return all users, always